# How to solve this integral $\int_0^{1}(2x^2+1)\sqrt{\frac{1-x^2}{1-x^8}}\ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_0^{1}(2x^2+1)\sqrt{\frac{1-x^2}{1-x^8}}\ dx$$

substituting $x^4=\sin u; dx=\frac{\cos u}{4(\sin u)^{3/4}}$

$$\frac1{4}\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\left(2\sqrt{\sin u}+1\right){\sqrt{1-\sqrt{\sin u}}}}{(\sin u)^{3/4}}\ du$$

$$\frac 1{2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sqrt{1-\sqrt{\sin u}}}{(\sin u)^{1/4}}du+\frac1{4}\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sqrt{1-\sqrt{\sin u}}}{(\sin u)^{3/4}}\ du$$

Comment: Try substituting $x^{2}$=$t$.

Comment: there are (at least) 2 ways of answering this question...  What is the context for this problem? knowing that will help someone give you the kind of answer that is helpful to you

Comment: Do you have a reason to assume the answer can be expressed in terms of elementary functions? It seems unlikely.

Comment: i was thinking maybe gamma function might work

Comment: $1-x^8=1^2-(x^4)^2=(1-x^4(1+x^4)=(1-x^2)(1+x^2)(1+x^4)$ does not help?

Comment: Since $y = x^2$ gives a linear function divided by the square root of a polynomial of degree four, we know there is a closed form in terms of elliptic integrals. After some simplifications, the integral is
$$\sqrt {\frac {17 \sqrt 2 - 24} 8} \left(
 \Pi(n \mid m) -
  \Pi {\left( n; \arcsin \frac n 2 \; \middle| \; m \right)} \right) +
 \frac {\ln 5} 2, \\
m = \frac {2 + \sqrt 2} 4, \quad n = 2 (\sqrt 2 - 1).$$